# IE8 Location of Settings

Tags: internet-explorer-8, windows-xp, windows-server-2003, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have two different IE8 client stations that are experiencing different behaviors in a web application. I would like to be able to compare the local settings of each IE installation to find the source of the problem. Besides for the registry are there any other files/locations that IE8 and Windows Server 2003(station one) and Windows XP(station two) use to store the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtually all of IE's settings are sprinkled in various registry locations. The only other settings are maintained within the WinINET cache database index, but these are binary blobs you cannot readily read, and are almost never related to any problems.